# JSONArray not getting all values Android SDK

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get all the installed apps list (package names) into a JSONArray in Android. The arrar is not getting all the apps and is getting truncated with com.

Here's the code I am using :

```
//get apps list from phone and populate <br>
    final PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager(); <br>
    //get a list of installed apps. <br>
    List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA); <br>
    int count= 0; <br>
    JSONArray jarr_appname = new JSONArray(); <br>
    JSONArray jarr_packagename = new JSONArray(); <br>
    for (ApplicationInfo appInfo : installedApplications) { <br>
        jarr_appname.put(appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)); <br>
        Log.d("OUTPUT", "Package name : " + appInfo.packageName); <br>
        jarr_packagename.put(appInfo.packageName); <br>
        Log.d("OUTPUT", "Name: " + appInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)); <br>
        count += 1; <br>
        System.out.println("Total Apps count " + count); <br>
        } <br>
    System.out.println("App Name in json array" + jarr_appname); <br>
    System.out.println("Package Name in json array" + jarr_packagename); <br>
```

**Output :**

`07-22 15:05:09.566: I/System.out(17395): Total Apps count 173
07-22 15:05:09.566: I/System.out(17395): App Name in json array["Stick Tennis","BBC Media",/* all remaining*/, "My Network"]
07-22 15:05:09.566: I/System.out(17395): Package Name in json array["air.com.sticksports.sticktennis","air.uk.co,bbc.android.mediaplayer",/* all remaining*/, "com.paypal.android.p2mobile","com`

Notice the last package name in "Package Name in json array" is starting with "com and there's nothing else after that.
Can anyone please tell me if I am missing anything?

Thanks

Comment: prase your json an check. i guess there is a limit (length) for a single log.

Comment: Do you mean Sys.out log has limit?

Comment: I am not sure about Sys.out but i guess i read about `Log.i` on SO somewhere.

Comment: I am able to get all the applications names list (173)  jarr_appname. So I dont understand what is the issue in displaying package names in same Sysout

Comment: @JPro -- I think what Raghunandan was trying to say was that, there is a limit on the number of characters that the Log can print out. It has nothing to do with package names or what not.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using eclipse just go 
Window > Preferences, go to the Run/Debug > Console section, then you should see an option "Limit console output." Here you can change the size.

Another way just use debug mode and find your json variable's value... it gives you full json.